# Retrofit 2.0 Crash on 4.1.1

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i am using retrofit 2.0  for networking , its working fine on android 5 + , just i tested     on android 4.1.1 i am getting crash

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder
```

but same code is working on 5+ devices

```
   retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

  my gradle

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

why its happing

Comment: issue already filed here follow [this link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1628)

Comment: can you share your full gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseURL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(httpClient)
        .build();
```

and this also

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.1'
```

Comment: but i am using GsonConverterFactory not scalars

Comment: then don't use that line

Comment: try using scalars

Comment: I am using the same thing and it is not crashing at all.

Comment: its coz of 2.1.0?